# Error:-Task not found in root project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, quickblox

I am trying to do quickblox chat sample in android studio.But getting this error

*********Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task '' not found in root project 'quickblox-android-sdk-master'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.*********

Comment: post your code and app gradle logcate also